# django collectstatic without db connection?

Tags: python, django

while I am running `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input` I am getting a DB connection issue. i want to collect statics without a DB connection to dockerize my Django app. with DB connection it's working fine.

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: information_schema.tables

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\test-app\test\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\projects\test-app\test\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\apps.py", line 46, in ready
    validate_extra_extensions()
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\utils.py", line 272, in validate_extra_extensions
    cursor.execute(
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\projects\test-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

manage.py does not require a DB connection to work, are you write any check condition for connection in your models.py file?

please if you can shear the full error and model

Comment: in model No. but i am using Django tenants (https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: please check the traceback in question

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to prevent `collectstatic` from trying to access the database. Using a dummy database in certain situations could solve your problem. If this doesn't help you will probably have to implement it yourself.

Because `collectstatic` does additional work based on the `STATICFILES_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Django tenants doing validation for extra extensions because of this we need a Postgres database connection while doing a static collection to skip this step we can configure `SKIP_PG_EXTRA_VALIDATION` attribute in the `settings.py`

```
SKIP_PG_EXTRA_VALIDATION = True
```